# Vector valued mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I sew in wiki the following theorem
[image]
Does anyone know a textbook including it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about proving it? Hints: consider $m=1$ and use how the gradient of a function is related to the directional derivative. It all boils down to the one dimensional case via the fundamental theorem of calculus.